# method to subtract text strings common in two files?

Tags: windows-xp, text-editors

I have two text files, one with 100,000 strings and the other with 1,000 strings, which are already present in the larger file.
I'd like to subtract those 1,000 strings, so that the larger file will then contain only 99,000.
This is not about removing duplicates, rather stripping out strings.

Is there a command to do so.

Comment: Which operating system are you running? This looks like something you could do over Linux command line with several different methods.

Comment: Win XP, I'm afraid...

Comment: Can you provide samples of both files with smaller size and what the expected results are?

Comment: Would you consider installing [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) in your Windows?

Comment: I would install MSYS!

Answer (score 0):

If the strings are all on separate lines, you can use [grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) from [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) or [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) as follows:

```
C:\> grep -v -f thousandLine.txt hundred000line.txt >ninetynine000Line.txt
```

The `-v` option inverts the match so that the output is all lines in `hundred000line.txt` that don't match any line in `thousandLine.txt`. See the [grep manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) for more information.